# Is it possible to programmatically trigger a slide transition during a presentation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

Does one know if there is a way to programmatically trigger a slide change during a presentation ?

I'd like to be able to share the "transition triggers" (back and forth at least) with some other attendes when I presenting during an online meeting or a video conference.

Due to covid and thus massive usage of online meeting these days, I guess :

- Either it already exist, and I didn't guessed which are the right terms to search for it on Google (or whichever search engine you like ;)
- Or it's not possible, and in that case, I'd like to understand why, in order to enhance my knowledge of all or part of Google Slide API and / or Google app script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answers:

> Does it already exist?

*No.*

> If it's not possible, why?

*Those at Google have not made the decision to implement it - perhaps because the feature has yet to be requested.*

#### Feature Request:

***You*** can however change this! You can let Google know that this is a feature that is important for access to their APIs, and that you would like to request they implement it.

Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services, I'd urge you to make a feature request there. The best component to file this under would be the [Apps Script component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113), with the `Feature Request` template.